# How Create programmaticaly Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> with variable Type?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, expression

I want to create below code

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>(expName, entity);
```

but TProperty type is variable and change in loop and i can get type of this :

```
var nameType = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(name);
```

I want to have like this

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, nameType>>(expName, entity);
```

Can I create this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Expression.Lamdba(Type, Expression, params ParameterExpression[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350515%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - you'd use `typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity), nameType)` to create the relevant type.

That will just give you a `LambdaExpression` though. It's not clear what you're trying to *do* with the result, but you won't have a strongly-typed expression you can invoke. (It will build the right delegate type when you compile it though.)